# printing character sequences

Tags: c++

**question**
   Using two characters: . (dot) and * (asterisk) print a grid-like pattern. The grid will have l lines, c columns, and each square shaped element of the grid will have the height and width equal to s.

Moreover, each of the grid elements will have a diagonal. The diagonal of the first square in the first line of the grid is directed towards down and right corner - use the \ (backslash) character to print it; while the next diagonal will be directed towards upper right corner - use the / (slash) character to print it. Print the successive diagonals alternately (please consult the example below).

Input

You are given t - the number of test cases and for each of the test case three positive integers: l - the number of lines, c - the number of columns in the grid and s - the size of the single square shaped element.

Output

For each of the test cases output the requested pattern (please have a look at the example). Use one line break in between successive patterns.

Example

```
Input:
3
3 1 2 
4 4 1 
2 5 2 

Output:
****
*\.*
*.\*
****
*./*
*/.*
****
*\.*
*.\*
****

*********
*\*/*\*/*
*********
*/*\*/*\*
*********
*\*/*\*/*
*********
*/*\*/*\*
*********

****************
*\.*./*\.*./*\.*
*.\*/.*.\*/.*.\*
****************
*./*\.*./*\.*./*
*/.*.\*/.*.\*/.*
****************
```

*my solution:*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int i,j,k,l,c,s,t;

   cin>>t;
    k=0;

   while(k<t)
   {
        cin>>l>>c>>s;
     for(i=0;i<(s-1)*l;i++)
      {
        for(j=0;j<(s-1)*c;j++)
            {
              if(i==j)
                  cout<<'\';
                else
                {
                  if(i%(s-1)==0||j%(s-1)==0)
                     cout<<'*';
                   else
                      {
                        if(i+j==(s-1))
                          cout<<'/';
                         else
                           cout<<'.';
                      }
                 }                
            } 
         cout<<"\n";
      }
      k++;
   } 



    return 0;
}
```

**problem**
giving compilation error!!! can't figure out why?

Comment: what is the compilation error ?

Comment: `cout<<'\';` -- the backspace is an escape character.  To print a backspace you need to use `cout<<'\\';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you notice, `cout<<'\';` the second `'` isn't the same color. That's because `\` is an escape character. It is escaping the `'`. You'll need to change it to `\\` anytime you want to use the backslash character itself.

Hope this helps!